# How to track the Http Protocol on the Server

Tags: 2007, administration, iis, tools

We do have many client specific tools (i.e. Httpwatch, Wfetch...) to track the Http Protocol however I want to track http protocol (headers) on the server end.

I mean to say that, How server communicates with the client on its http request

Please let me know if we have any tool to do this on the server end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like [WinDump](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.wiretapped.net/pub/security/packet-capture/winpcap/windump/), or an other protocol analyser, and then look at the many [tcp dump tutorials](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=using+tcpdump+http&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Another good tool is [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Could always look at the IIS logs. If not, what sort of detail are you after?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [Netmon (Network monitor)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) to track all kinds of network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Log is the best option to start with. This will give you all the details that you need. Do configure it first to show the http protocol. It's a tick box in the properties window for the IIS log settings.